# Submit Multipart/form-data form to ASP Web Api using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, form-submit

I know this question has been asked alot and i tried every single solution, but it just won't work for me.

I have a ASP WEB API which looks like this:

```
private string uploadFolder = ("~/uploads");

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
    {
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var a in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    sb.Append(a.ToString());
                }
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it is a pretty simple one that is able too accept multipart/form-data.

The Ajax code i am using is the following:

```
 $("#form1").submit(function (e) {

        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var submitUrl = "api/upload";

        $.ajax({
            url: submitUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function() {
                //window.location("Upload.html");
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(this).submit();
```

The form i am sending only contains a textfield and a submit button. When i click the submit button, i get an error: 405 Method not allowed.

When i insert the script into chrome and run it from there it gets to the API, but on

> await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)

it throws an exception in my catch.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: How are your routes configured? The 405 can be caused when Web API finds a matching route but the associated operations do not support `POST`  . And what do you mean by 'When I insert the script into chrom...'? How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: The routes are set to default. In the Config.cs the i#ve got the following:


routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
default: new{id = RouteParameter.Optional}

And about your second question. If you press Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome you get to the inspection window, there you can select "Console", post a script in the text window and run it by pressing enter.